# Cleanup failed linux kernel update

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, dpkg

Good evening!

**SITUATION**:
I ran into a quite stupid problem, I know my LVM boot partition is not cleaning up properly old kernels and I have to do it manually, thus I forgot last time and now I am somehow stuck with a half-way installed linux-image-4.4.0-43.
At first, I had the issue that when trying to update I had the message "not enough space" (something like that), so I followed the steps from [THIS LINK](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/RemoveOldKernels#Unmet_Dependency_Errors).
uname -r returns the current running kernel is 4.4.0-42 (fine)
when is ran the dpkg -l command I get a slightly different list:

```
pi  linux-image-4.4.0-34-generic                4.4.0-34.53                                                 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-36-generic                4.4.0-36.55                                                 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
pF  linux-image-4.4.0-43-generic                4.4.0-43.63                                                 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

if I want to remove the last entry for the kernel 4.4.0-43 I always get unresolved dependencies (basically the 4.4.0-43-generic being dependent on the 4.4.0-43 packages)

**PROBLEM**:
when I boot my PC now the booting stops and I have to press power button for few seconds and restart the machine, so I get into GRUB and can manually select the 4.4..0-42-generic kernel from the list
the 43 kernel is the top entry in the list to select from in GRUB.

**ASSUMPTION**:
my assumption is now that the new kernel is somewhat half way installed but not working properly. this is based on the output of the update-grub2 command:

```
Warnung: Werte ungleich 0 für »GRUB_TIMEOUT« werden, falls »GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT« aktiviert ist, nicht mehr unterstützt.
Linux-Abbild gefunden: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-43-generic
Linux-Abbild gefunden: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-42-generic
initrd-Abbild gefunden: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-42-generic
Linux-Abbild gefunden: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-36-generic
initrd-Abbild gefunden: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-36-generic
Linux-Abbild gefunden: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-34-generic
initrd-Abbild gefunden: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-34-generic
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
```

**QUESTION**:
how do I fix this? I assume I have to remove somehow the new kernel entry and re-install it - but I am stuck/lost. I have read so many posts and links already, I am totally confused (not the biggest Linux pro - I guess you figured that already)

Any help is appreciated, thanks

**UPDATE** asked for:
ls -alh /boot

```
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 3,0K Okt 14 17:16 .
drwxr-xr-x 25 root root 4,0K Okt 14 17:16 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1,2M Jul 27 23:28 abi-4.4.0-34-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1,2M Aug 11 21:58 abi-4.4.0-36-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1,2M Okt  8 04:15 abi-4.4.0-42-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1,2M Okt 12 17:47 abi-4.4.0-43-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 186K Jul 27 23:28 config-4.4.0-34-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 186K Aug 11 21:58 config-4.4.0-36-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 186K Okt  8 04:15 config-4.4.0-42-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 186K Okt 12 17:47 config-4.4.0-43-generic
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4,0K Jan  1  1970 efi
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 1,0K Okt 17 19:49 grub
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  35M Sep  1 18:55 initrd.img-4.4.0-34-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  35M Sep 16 17:23 initrd.img-4.4.0-36-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  37M Okt 13 18:38 initrd.img-4.4.0-42-generic
drwx------  2 root root  12K Apr 14  2016 lost+found
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 179K Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 181K Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 181K Jan 28  2016 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-------  1 root root 3,7M Jul 27 23:28 System.map-4.4.0-34-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 3,7M Aug 11 21:58 System.map-4.4.0-36-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 3,7M Okt  8 04:15 System.map-4.4.0-42-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 3,7M Okt 12 17:47 System.map-4.4.0-43-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 6,8M Jul 27 23:28 vmlinuz-4.4.0-34-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 6,8M Aug 11 21:58 vmlinuz-4.4.0-36-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 6,8M Sep  3 09:49 vmlinuz-4.4.0-36-generic.efi.signed
-rw-------  1 root root 6,8M Okt  8 04:15 vmlinuz-4.4.0-42-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 6,8M Okt 13 18:38 vmlinuz-4.4.0-42-generic.efi.signed
-rw-------  1 root root 6,8M Okt 12 17:47 vmlinuz-4.4.0-43-generic
```

df -hTa /boot

```
/dev/sdb2      ext2  237M    178M   47M   80% /boot
```

**UPDATE2**:
the removal of 4.4.0-34-generic and 4.4.0-36-generic has worked, I guess.
reinstall of 4.4.0-43-generic seems to be succesful from what I can understand.

Comment: Can you add the output of `ls -alh /boot` and `df -hTa /boot` to your question. Sometimes `dkms` leaves backup `initrd` which also take a lot of space and are not needed.

Comment: updated with info.

Comment: Can you remove kernels `linux-image-4.4.0-34-generic`  and `linux-image-4.4.0-36-generic` with `apt-get purge  linux-image-4.4.0-34-generic linux-image-4.4.0-36-generic`? After that, try to run `apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-4.4.0-43-generic`.

Comment: Will update later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot @Thomas.

the removal of the last two remaining linux images and in the last consequence the

```
apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-4.4.0-43-generic
```

solved the issue.